# OpenLayers Icon with ngClick

Tags: openlayers, google-maps, markers, icon

I am working off the OpenLayers Icon Symbolizer example (https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html) to create an equivalent to a Google Maps marker

```
new google.maps.Marker({...})
```

With Google Maps, I was able to add a listener and assign the ngClick event I had defined for the html element that created the marker. This way, when I clicked on the marker, it would trigger the ngClick function:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(scope.marker, 'click', function() {
     scope.$apply(function() {
             scope.ngClick()
     };
});
```

However, now that I am using the Open Layers icon, which is being added via adding a layer, I am not sure how I can link the ngClick function. This could be applied to any function that I am trying to pass on the icon click event like I had with marker. Everything I saw online, so far, has suggested that this needs to happen via map but I have not had success with it so far:

```
map.on('click', function(evt){
     var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,
         function(feature) {
           scope.ngClick();
     });
});
```

While this does not throw any errors, it does not trigger my ngClick function. The example shows how to add my own popup to the icon but I want to specifically tie a predefined function to the Marker/Icon click which may be different for different markers.

Can anyone recommend what I am missing?

Comment: If you have marker/icon defined as a feature as it is in example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon.html, this should work.

Comment: @TomazicM I'm unclear how this would work. Google Maps allowed me to add a listener and bind the ngClick action of the HTML marker element to the Marker. The link you posted shows a click event on the map but how do I tie it to the ngClick of the marker/icon?

Comment: Method `map.forEachFeatureAtPixel` finds feature (marker in this case) at the click coordinates and returns marker object. In the mentioned example popup is then displayed above marker.

Comment: @TomazicM I get how the example works, however, I am trying to trigger a function defined in the marker's ng-click field. Say I don't want to display a popup but, instead, trigger a function I passed in. Google Maps allows me to do this via addListener. I believe OpenLayers used to allow this when it has click event for markers. Now that click event are on the map, how can I trigger the ng-Click function when the marker is clicked?

Comment: At what level is this `ng-Click` function defined?

Comment: I have a div implementing a directive that created the marker/icon. This div has an ng-Click function defined. Really the function can come from anywhere, I just want to tie it to the marker/icon click like I was able to do in Google Maps.

Comment: It's hard to guess what is wrong without seeing some of your code. Did you try to debug? Are there any errors displayed in console?